# Run multiple functions at different time intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, delay

I have four functions,

```
functionOne();
functionTwo();
functionThree();
functionFour();
```

All I want to do is to call these functions for different time durations, that is,

```
// run functionOne
functionOne();
// delay for a duration of 200ms

//run functionTwo
functionTwo();
// delay for a duration of 600ms

// run functionThree
functionThree();
// delay for a duration of 200ms

// run functionFour
functionFour();
// delay for a duration of 1600ms

// repeat from one again!
```

I know, `setInterval(functionOne, time);` can loop the `functionOne` at specific time.

How can I make the functions run in the order of duration given above?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? do you need to start the first one, then finish it and start the next one or start all of them at the same exact moment?

Comment: I don't understand whay you mean by "run for a duration of 200ms" . You can't choose for how long you want to run a function. What you could do is to wait for 200ms after functionOne to run functionTwo. Is that what you want ?

Comment: You can delay a function's execution, but you can't dictate when it has to stop. Should we assume that the function definitely stops within that time, or ... ?

Comment: @briosheje Yeah, same order

Comment: aha downvote? let me know the reason!!

Comment: @edi9999 i just meant to delay the fucntion for the specific time

Comment: I downvoted because the question is quite unclear and will probably not help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var the_time = 1000;
var funArr = [funcitonOne,funcitonTwo,funcitonThree,funcitonFore];
for (var i=0; i<funArr.length;i++){
  setInterval(funArr[i], the_time*(i+1));
}
```

**UPDATE:**

duration be passed in to the function:

```
function funcitonOne(time) {
    console.log('funcitonOne', time);
}
function funcitonTwo(time) {
    console.log('funcitonTwo', time);
}
var funArr = [funcitonOne, funcitonTwo];
for (var i = 0; i < funArr.length; i++) {
    var interval = 500 * (i + 1);
    (function (i,interval) {
        setInterval(function(){
            funArr[i].call(this, interval);
        }, interval);
    }(i,interval));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[functionOne(),functionTwo(),functionThree(),functionFour()]`? 1) Watch your spelling... 2) If you are storing functions in array, you still need `()` right?

Comment: @chris97ong no need, *functionOne* is a variable, *functionOne()* will do execute.

Comment: what is `the_time` ? can i store the time somewhere and use along?

Comment: @sdfsdf yes, the_time is the interval time variable, as I update above.

Comment: I mean if the duration can be passed in to the function?